# Firebase Storage User Ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase for a project, I need to store images in a folder for the users. For example, images/userId/images. At this moment, the rules of my Firebase database rules are:

```
service firebase.storage {
  enter code here`match /b/<your-firbase-storage-bucket>/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to put the ref in my code for point to the correct folder in database.

I tried below in my code, but didn't work.

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(Items/${file.name}
```

What should I do to refer correctly my code to the Firebase storage?

Answer (score 0):

To Refer to your storage use:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("YOUR STORAGE URL AS SHOWN WITH IN THE IMAGE (BLACK BOX)");
```

[image]

and then refer the folder within the upload task:

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/" + userid + "/" + file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);
```

for more reference see : 
[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

It has all the methods showing ways to uploading data using a stream or from memory or using a file(above example is for a file upload).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user is signed in:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("user");
var userRef = storageRef.child(user.uid);
```